# Responsively crop 4:3 image into 16:9

Tags: css, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to responsively crop a YouTube 4:3 thumbnail image, which includes black bars, down to 16:9, but I'm not achieving the exact aspect ratio. For some reason, despite being a 1080p video, the highest res image I can get is 640x480.

HTML:

```
<figure class="sixteen-nine-img">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kTnvan3vws4/sddefault.jpg" alt="Video: Lincoln Center Festival 2017: George Balanchine's JEWELS">
</figure>
```

CSS:

```
figure.sixteen-nine-img {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

figure.sixteen-nine-img img {
  display: block;
  margin: -21.875% 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Demo: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/bqoYoM)

Comment: like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PpJOaQ

Comment: @MichaelCoker That's it! Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can absolutely position and center the image in the container, then make the parent height 16:9 responsively by using %-based padding top/bottom that represents the 16:9 ratio (9/16 = 56.25%)

```css
figure.sixteen-nine-img {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  position: relative;
}
figure.sixteen-nine-img img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<figure class="sixteen-nine-img">
    <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/kTnvan3vws4/sddefault.jpg" alt="Video: Lincoln Center Festival 2017: George Balanchine's JEWELS">
</figure>
```